# How can I send the same email message to more than 3000 customers

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

I want to send the same email message to more than 3000 customers, What is the best, shortest way to do that?, Is there a tool takes a list of emails addresses and the email body?  Note: I have mail server

Comment: then what's the problem? Spam filter?

Comment: i think you are looking for some Mass mailer programs available , you may google for it, i think http://www.massmailersoft.com/ should suit you

Comment: @Akash Yadav: Thanks a lot, but Is there a freeware tool

Comment: @JustMe i think this might suit you http://pommo.org/Main_Page

Comment: If you have 3000+ customer - why do you need a **freeware** to send them mail?? Don't those customers **pay** you so you could sign up for a commercial service??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Customer> customerList = GetAllCustomers();

string subject = "Hello World";
string content = GetContent();

// Loop through all customers and send e-mail to each
foreach(Customer customer in customerList)
{
   MailMessage newMail = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", customer.Email, subject, content);

   newMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

   SmtpClient sender = new SmtpClient();

   sender.Send(newMail);
}
```

You can move the GetContent() within the loop if you have a customer personalised email.

I hope you have their permission to send them e-mails. I share this code with you on the premise that it will **not** be used to spam people.